# Renaming multiple files separated by special character by changing order

Tags: bash, shell, file, rename

I have thousands of files I want to rename.

Each file name has one of the following structures :

- aa - bb.txt
- aa - bb - cc.txt
- aa - bb - cc - dd.txt
- aa - bb - cc - dd - ee.txt

With [aa], [bb], [cc], [dd] and [ee] changing among files, and varying in length.

I would like to have the last element before `.txt` (the file name consists of multiple special characters `-`) at the beginning.

For the examples above, this would result in:

- bb - aa.txt
- cc - aa - bb.txt
- dd - aa - bb - cc.txt
- ee - aa - bb - cc - dd.txt

How could I do this using a Bash command?

Comment: Are they all in a single directory, or spread all round the filesystem?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, all files are in a single directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure BASH solution, could you please try following. Tested and written with shown samples only.

```
for fileName in *.txt
do
  lastPartFileName="${fileName##*- }"
  firstPartFileName="${fileName%- *}"
  firstPartFileName1="${fileName## *}"
  firstPartFileName2="${firstPartFileName1% *}"
  firstPartFileName3=${firstPartFileName2% -*}
  lastPartFileName1=$(echo "$lastPartFileName" | cut -d'.' -f1)
  echo "mv \"$fileName\" \"$lastPartFileName1 - $firstPartFileName3.txt\""
done
```

Output will be as follows.

```
mv "aa - bb - cc - dd - ee.txt" "ee - aa - bb - cc - dd.txt"
mv "aa - bb - cc - dd.txt" "dd - aa - bb - cc.txt"
mv "aa - bb - cc.txt" "cc - aa - bb.txt"
mv "aa - bb.txt" "bb - aa.txt"
```

It will print `mv`(rename) commands once you are happy with results looking then run following by appending  `| bash` to above command's after `done` like  `done | bash`.

Answer (score 3):

As always, backup your files or test on a copied subset before running unfamiliar commands as powerful as this one...

I think you can do it with `rename`, a.k.a. `Perl rename` like this:

```
rename -n 's/.txt$//; my @F=split / - /; $_ = join " - ", pop @F, @F; $_ .= ".txt"' *.txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
'aa - bb - cc - dd - ee.txt' would be renamed to 'ee - aa - bb - cc - dd.txt'
'aa - bb - cc - dd.txt' would be renamed to 'dd - aa - bb - cc.txt'
'aa - bb - cc.txt' would be renamed to 'cc - aa - bb.txt'
'aa - bb.txt' would be renamed to 'bb - aa.txt'
```

If unfamiliar with Perl, that means... *"Rename as a dry-run without actually doing anything because of `-n`. Remove the `.txt` extension. Split the filename on "space-space" into a list called `F`. Make a new output filename by joining the last element popped off list `F` to all the remaining elements of the list `F` using `" - "` to separate elements. Put the ".txt" extension back on."*

---

If you have so many files that you get *"Argument list too long"* error, you can refactor that into:

```
find . -name "*-*.txt" -print0 " | rename -0 -n 's/.txt$//; my @F=split / - /; $_ = join " - ", pop @F, @F; $_ .= ".txt"'
```

Add `-maxdepth 1` into the `find` command if you do not want to recurse down into lower directories.

---

If anyone tries this on macOS, you can install the correct `rename` command with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this zsh function:

```
rename () {
    setopt local_options re_match_pcre
    if [[ "$1" =~ '(.*) - ([^-]*)(\.[^.]*)$' ]]
    then
        mv -i "$1" "${match[2]} - ${match[1]}${match[3]}"
    fi
}
```

```
rename *
```